# Dystopian novel about women and men being separated

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

This is essentially a third-hand search, sorry.  As the title states, I'm looking for information on a novel (published in the '80s possibly) or short story about a dystopian future in which women are mythological creatures to men. One man sets out to find this being and comes across a campfire in the wilderness and as he approaches the fire he says "Hey babe, what's your sign?"

Any help would be appreciated, but I won't be able to positively confirm if something is correct I can just say whether it sounds like what he's looking for.

(The first thing that popped into my head was an anime named "Vandread" because of similar subject matter, however, he was definite that it was a novel.)